# VSCode batch rename file using parsed filename

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-rename

I have a folder of ''date+index'' pdf files that I need to re-order the date format.
Current format ddmmyyyy_index.pdf.  Example: 01012006_1.pdf.
I want the format to be yyyy_mm_dd-index.pdf.  Result example 2006_01_01-1.pdf.
The first hurdle is getting the file name parsed and re-ordered.  The optional task is to take all months and days that begin with '0' to drop the '0', so the final result would be 2006_1_1-1.pdf.

I would like to use vscode to do this, but any common script type is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by using VS Code to re-order the date format; however, you can use TypeScript to do so:

```js
const str: string = '01012006_1.pdf'
const day: string = str.match(/.{1,2}/g)[0]
const month: string = str.match(/.{1,2}/g)[1].match(/.{1,2}/g)[0]
const year: string = str.match(/.{1,4}/g)[1]
const index: string = str.split('_')[1]

result = year + '_' + month.replace('0', '') + '_' + day.replace('0', '') + '-' + index + '.pdf'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply 6cloud9.
However, you're dealing with a noob.

If I copy and paste your code and save it as rename.ts, what should I do next?   Is that even the right thing to do?   And my goal is for the script to rename every file within the directory... say c:\temp.

Comment: @GregAppelt So, when you say you want to use VS Code to do this, do you mean you want to create a VS Code extension? Otherwise, VS Code is not really needed, except for using it simply as a code editor to write your script.